# How to update the default song metadata?

Tags: android, metadata, media-player, audio-player, android-music-player

I wanted to update the song metadata fields of Track, album, genre, artist and song cover image like Musicmatch.

I tried to look for the code to update the meta couldn't find any solutions.

Comment: please show us some code ...

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, well your question shows lack of research here, and **`FYI`** StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can **[help with certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**, but it's your job to **[put some efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7666442)** in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://www.google.co.in/)**. Read **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the metadata of a song we can do by using ID3 tags. We can update these using Mp3Tag editor - https://github.com/aminb/id3r
, MyID3() editor - https://github.com/ericfarng/jid3lib
 and Jaudiotagger - https://github.com/Adonai/jaudiotagger.

Mp3Tag editor - Only Mp3 song type is supported
MyID3 editor - Can edit song easily but not all field provided is updated
Jaudiotagger - This supports 
    Mp3,
    Flac,
    OggVorbis,
    Mp4,
    Aiff,
    Wav,
    Wma,
    Dsf
audio formats
It updated data without any issue

```
try {
      val audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file)
            val tag = audioFile?.tagOrCreateAndSetDefault
             tag?.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST, binding?.tiArtist?.text?.toString())
            tag?.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM, binding?.tiAlbum?.text?.toString())
            tag?.setField(FieldKey.GENRE, binding?.tiGenre?.text?.toString())
            tag?.setField(FieldKey.TITLE, binding?.tiTrack?.text?.toString())

            // Handle the image setting
            try {
                    val pfd = contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r") ?: return

                    val fis = FileInputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor)
                    val imgBytes = JavaUtils.readFully(fis)
                    val cover = AndroidArtwork()
                    cover.binaryData = imgBytes
                    cover.mimeType = ImageFormats.getMimeTypeForBinarySignature(byteArray)
                    cover.description = ""
                    cover.pictureType = PictureTypes.DEFAULT_ID
                    tag?.deleteArtworkField()
                    tag?.setField(cover)
                    fis.close()

              // to do check the file write option for both internal and external card
             // Handle the Storage Access FrameWork API if song is from SD card
            if (audioFile?.file?.let { SafUtils.isSafNeeded(it, this) } == true) {
              // Handle writing into SD card
              // Check if SAF permission is provided then only we can update metadata 
             // If SAF Permission is not provided. EACCESS : Permission Denied error is displayed 
            // After the permission success then only we can update meta.
                 writeIntoSDCard()
            } else {
                // Handle writing into internal card
                writeInInternalStorage()
            }
         } catch (e: Exception) { }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Show error on failure while writing
        } catch (e: Error) {
            // Show error on failure while writing
        }
```

Writing the metadata

```
// After update refresh the file else the changes will not be reflected
AudioFileIO.write(audioFile)
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(file?.absolutePath ?: ""), null, null)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your question isn't about a problem and is not detailed. But I can give you a great Media Player from google samples named UAMP(Universal Android Media Player) with handle all about android media player. [Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer)

UAMP uses a MediaMetadataCompat to update the song metadata like below code segment.

```
fun MediaMetadataCompat.Builder.from(jsonMusic: JsonMusic): MediaMetadataCompat.Builder {
// The duration from the JSON is given in seconds, but the rest of the code works in
// milliseconds. Here's where we convert to the proper units.
val durationMs = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(jsonMusic.duration)

id = jsonMusic.id
title = jsonMusic.title
artist = jsonMusic.artist
album = jsonMusic.album
duration = durationMs
genre = jsonMusic.genre
mediaUri = jsonMusic.source
albumArtUri = jsonMusic.image
trackNumber = jsonMusic.trackNumber
trackCount = jsonMusic.totalTrackCount
flag = MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE

// To make things easier for *displaying* these, set the display properties as well.
displayTitle = jsonMusic.title
displaySubtitle = jsonMusic.artist
displayDescription = jsonMusic.album
displayIconUri = jsonMusic.image

// Add downloadStatus to force the creation of an "extras" bundle in the resulting
// MediaMetadataCompat object. This is needed to send accurate metadata to the
// media session during updates.
downloadStatus = STATUS_NOT_DOWNLOADED

// Allow it to be used in the typical builder style.
return this
```

}

By this component, you can update song data in the notification, lock screen, and home screen.